# Moving screen by moving cursor in Parrot OS

Tags: desktop-environment

Please solve my issue of moving screen and magnified screen in my Parrot OS with the movement of cursor.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using on Parrot OS?

Comment: The question doesn't state what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System settings -> Workspace environments  -> Desktop effects -> Uncheck on zoom option